# For the same Conditional Probability, why does Bayes's Theorem differ from a direct calculation?

Tags: probability, proof-verification, bayes-theorem

Abbreviate: $D =$ a person is diseased, $+ =$ the test is positive.
Assume: $\Pr(D) = 0.001, \; \Pr(+|D)=0.99, \; \Pr(+|D^C) = 0.01  \qquad ($[$\iff$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/825698/53259) $ \Pr(-|D^C) = 0.99).$

**1. Use [Bayes's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/198677/53259)**: $\Pr(D|+) = 0.0 \; 90 \; 1639... \quad $ (confirmed; scroll down 30% [hereof](http://betterexplained.com/articles/an-intuitive-and-short-explanation-of-bayes-theorem)).

**2. Quantify the above probabilities for 1000 people (per [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/869134/53259) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1438167/53259))**
(Table [herefrom](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198691/53259). Green indicates True results, red False results).

$$\begin{array}{r|cc|c}
&D &\lnot D  &\text{Total}\\ \hline
+&\color{green}{\Pr(D)\Pr(+|D)}&\color{red}{\Pr(D^C)\Pr(+|D^C)}&\text{add the 2 left entries}\\
- &\color{red}{\Pr(D)\Pr(-|D)}&\color{green}{\Pr(D^C)\Pr(-|D^C)}&\color{black}{\text{add the 2 left entries}}\\ \hline
\text{Total}&\color{black}{1}&\color{black}{999}&\color{black}{1000}
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{r|cc|c}
&D &\lnot D  &\text{Total}\\ \hline
+&\color{green}{1}&\color{red}{9.99}&10.99\\
- &\color{red}{\text{impertinent}}&\color{green}{\text{impertinent}}&\color{black}{\text{impertinent}}\\ \hline
\text{Total}&\color{black}{1}&\color{black}{999}&\color{black}{1000}
\end{array}$$

$3.$ So $\Pr(D|+) = \dfrac{ \color{green}{1} }{ 10.99 } = 0.0 \; 90 \; 9918... \quad $

Why do 1 and 3 differ starting at the ten-thousandth digit?

Comment: Your $9.9$ should be $9.99$. Also, your $1$ should be $0.99$.  Too much rounding.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I incorporated your first sentence. But why should my $1$ be $0.99$?

Comment: Only $99\%$ of people with the disease test positive. The total $10000$  used by Adriano makes things  more clear.

Comment: Basically, the "impertinent" is not *irrelevant*, as it would show where the error lay. $\;$ Since there is a non-zero *something* in the red "impertinent" cell, the cell above it *can not* contain $1$. $\;$ It must be $1-\color{red}{\textsf{impertinent}}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is due to roundoff error. Try instead using $100000$ people:

$$\begin{array}{r|cc|c}
&D &\lnot D  &\text{Total}\\ \hline
+&\color{green}{99}&\color{red}{999}&1098\\
- &\color{red}{1}&\color{green}{98901}&\color{black}{98902}\\ \hline
\text{Total}&\color{black}{100}&\color{black}{99900}&\color{black}{100000}
\end{array}$$

So:
$$
\Pr[D \mid +] = \frac{99}{1098} = \frac{11}{122} = 0.090163934\ldots
$$

Comment: Thanks; though I just corrected my OP, I do not see the 'roundoff' error. Why should my $1$ be $0.99$?

Comment: Because that entry in the table has a probability of:
$$
\Pr[D \text{ and } +] = \Pr[D] \cdot \Pr[+ \mid D] = (0.001)(0.99) = 0.00099
$$
so multiplying by your total of $1000$ people yields $0.99$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user 'Adriano' 's answer, I recognised the problem: I neglected to calculate precisely the four numbers in the middle entry which should instead be:

$$\begin{array}{r|cc|c}
&D &\lnot D  &\text{Total}\\ \hline
+&\color{green}{0.99}&\color{red}{9.99}&10.98\\
- &\color{red}{ 0.01 }&\color{green}{989.01}&\color{black}{\text{989.02}}\\ \hline
\text{Total}&\color{black}{1}&\color{black}{999}&\color{black}{1000}
\end{array}$$

$3.$ So $\Pr(D|+) = \dfrac{ \color{green}{0.99} }{ 10.98 } = 0.0 \; 90 \; 1639344... \quad $